# Как сделать Setting WebView

Tags: android, webview

Всем привет я новичек и хочу как сделать настройки для WebView 
Чтобы можно было изменять их в самом приложении 
Например включить JavaScript или выключить , но вот не знаю как сделать чтобы можно было менять WebView1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  этот true  параметр на false  при помощи кнопки или галочки 
Дайте пожалуйста пример кода

Comment: А вы не попробовали? Если да, то добавьте код.

Comment: Нет я вообще не могу понять как все это сделать

Comment: Можете пример скинуть готового кода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На экране настроек меняйте значения в `SharedPreferences`, вызывая этот метод, передавая ему `true` или `false`, чтобы включить/выключить. Аналогично с любыми настройками, ключ `jsEnabled` в кавычках только меняйте, каждый ключ для одного сохраненного значения

```
public void switchJS(boolean jsEnabled){
   SharedPreferences shared = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
   editor.putInt("jsEnabled", jsEnabled ? 1 : 0);
   editor.commit();
}
```

А в `WebView` делать так

```
SharedPreferences shared = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
int jsEnabled = shared.getInt("jsEnabled", 0);
webView.setJavaScriptEnabled(jsEnabled == 1 ? true : false);
```

Писал код не в IDE, но вроде суть ясна. Если что-то не ясно почитайте [эту статью](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/sharedpreferences.php)

Comment: Кто точно знает - костыль с int это нормально?

Comment: Спасибо большое !

Comment: а в сам файл xml какой код сделать например чтобы галочка была можете помочь

Comment: Вот еще класс-хелпер, для работы с настройками, везде его использую, но конечно сначала изучите "работу руками" https://github.com/nickescobedo/Android-Shared-Preferences-Helper/blob/master/SharedPreferenceHelper.java

Comment: Хорошо спасибо  большое а то весь день уже мучаюсь и не могу сделать

Comment: Если вам помог мой ответ, отметьте его верным (галочка слева)